# Fortran90 Makefile with pre-compilation and modules

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90, precompile, pre-compilation

I'm trying to write a **Makefile** to compile a **Fortran90** project that consists of several source files containing subroutines and **modules**. To make things more complicated, I'm using **pre-compilation** (creating `*.for` files from `*.F` files). I could not find any answer to this, but this may be because I get confused by the different styles of Makefile syntax.

I created a stripped-down version for reproducing my problem (available on https://github.com/stineb/stackoverflow). This contains a main program (`sayhello.F`), two subroutines in separate source files (`schleppe.F` and `schnuppi.F`), and two modules in separate source files (`words_schleppe.mod.F` and `words_schnuppi.mod.F`). The executable is `hello`.

I am able to build it with a simple Makefile and avoiding the pre-compilation. This file (Makefile_simple) looks like this:

```make
FCOM=gfortran
EXE = hello

standard: 
    $(FCOM) -c words_schleppe.mod.F
    $(FCOM) -c words_schnuppi.mod.F
    $(FCOM) -c schleppe.F
    $(FCOM) -c schnuppi.F
    $(FCOM) words_schleppe.mod.o words_schnuppi.mod.o schleppe.o schnuppi.o sayhello.F -o $(EXE)

 .PHONY: clean
 clean:
    rm $(EXE) *.o *.mod
```

However, my project will be a bit bigger than this so I want to make use of the cryptic features of a more complex Makefile for defining rules. And crucially: I want to pre-compile source files `*.F` into `.for`. This is where I haven't managed to define the rules to create the `.mod` files from the modules and build the whole thing. Disregarding the modules, I do get it running with the following Makefile (`Makefile_complex` on my github repository):

```make
FCOM=gfortran
CPPFLAGS=-e
COMPFLAGS=
EXE=hello
SOURCES=sayhello.F schleppe.F schnuppi.F 
OBJS=$(SOURCES:.F=.o)

all: $(OBJS)
    # this may also be replaced by the ar command (creating archive)
    $(FCOM) $(OBJS) -o $(EXE)

%.for: %.F
    rm -f $*.for
    $(FCOM) $(CPPFLAGS) $*.F > $*.for

$(OBJS): %.o: %.for
    $(FCOM) -c -o $@ $(COMPFLAGS) $*.for

# clean: remove .for, .o, .do, and .stb files
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f *.for *.o *.stb *.mod
```

What do I have to add to this in order to include the modules in the build? The dependencies are as follows: `subroutine schleppe` <- `module words_schleppe`; and `subroutine schnuppi` <- `module words_schnuppi`.

Help, anyone?
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: How does one make `.mod` files from the modules (are those the `.mod.F` files)? How are those `.mod` files then used in the rest of the build process?

Comment: @EtanReisner the `.mod` files are created by the compiler automatically when compiling the source files which happen to contain a module. They are used implicitly by the same compiler when they encounter any `use` statement.

Comment: Do you mean that compiling `schleppe.F` will generate `schleppe.for` and that compiling `words_schleppe.mod.F` will generate `words_schleppe.mod` automatically using the same compilation command?

Comment: @EtanReisner, yes, this is the case.

Comment: Then I think you just want to duplicate the bit about `OBJS` with `MODS` and add a `%.mod: %.F` recipe and matching `$(MODS): %.o: %.mod` recipe (if that is necessary also).

Comment: Simple solution: The rule for `all:` must include the module source files, and these must precede the other source files. Plus, rules of creating the object files from the module source files have to be added. The working Makefile looks like this:

Comment: @stineb Don't edit your question, post the solution as an answer and accept it !

Comment: Sorry, first time user ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION! Simply, the rule for `all:` must include the module source files, and these **must precede** the other source files. Plus, rules of creating the object files from the module source files have to be added. The working Makefile looks like this:

```
FCOM=gfortran

CPPFLAGS=-E
COMPFLAGS=

EXE=hello

SOURCES=sayhello.F schleppe.F schnuppi.F
MODS=words_schleppe.F words_schnuppi.F

OBJS=$(SOURCES:.F=.o)
MODOBJS=$(MODS:.F=.o)

# this may also be replaced by the ar command (creating archive)
all: $(MODOBJS) $(OBJS)
    $(FCOM) $(OBJS) $(MODOBJS) -o $(EXE)

%.for: %.F
    rm -f $*.for
    $(FCOM) $(CPPFLAGS) $*.F > $*.for

$(MODOBJS): %.o: %.for
    $(FCOM) -c -o $@ $(COMPFLAGS) $*.for

$(OBJS): %.o: %.for
    $(FCOM) -c -o $@ $(COMPFLAGS) $*.for

# clean: remove .for, .o, .do, and .stb files
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f *.for *.o *.stb *.mod
```